# How to check form a View Controller that Push Notification is Come?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to check  form a View Controller that Push Notification is Come in iOS?

Answer (score 0):

As you're obviously trying to catch an push notification while your application is active, I'd highly recommend to check the `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` method, which is called in your `AppDelegate` when an push notification is received.

To notify a specific view controller, you may use *delegates*.

As there are a lot of tutorials and articles about how to set up an delegate class, I will not go much into details.

As an idea, the delegate class may look like this:

PushNotificationDelegate.h

```
@protocol PushNotificationDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void)didReceivePushNotificationWithUserInfo:(NSDictionary *)userInfo;
@end
```

The above mentioned method may look like this in the AppDelegate.m file.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))handler {
    [delegate didReceivePushNotificationWithUserInfo:userInfo];
}
```

In your view controller, you would implement the delegate method like this:

ViewController.m

```
- (void)didReceivePushNotificationWithUserInfo:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

// your code goes here...

}
```

I did not test that solution but you may tell me, if it worked or not.